# IntelliJ refactor rename is too powerful, how to minimise it?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Its getting to the stage in my app that using the refactor rename functionality in IntelliJ is dangerous.

For example renaming a property on a hibernate entity will result in IntelliJ renaming all code and text occurences of that word.

Changing sql files, code comments, liquibase xmls, annotations

Thankfully my unit tests will pick up most cases when a breaking change is applied.
However in some cases, it will rename obscure things in my code which I will have to manually check with git commits to see what broke my app.

In fairness, the refactor does prompt you to exclude string occurences, however that is a manual task every time. Is there a way to by default get IntelliJ to only rename code occurrences?

Comment: Better ask this on the jetbrains community

Comment: Doesn't quite answer your question but you can use the preview functionality and exclude any changes you don't want to happen. See the [_Rename Refactoring_](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/rename-refactorings.html) section of Intellij's help documentation.

Answer (score 0):

While applying rename refactoring you can disable *search in comments and strings* option as well as *search for text occurrences*. This option is remembered between restarts so you don't need to uncheck it each time. Please describe what behaviour do you expect? Thank you